# local Domino Server for XPages Development - How to set up multiple internet Sites with localhost?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I have a locally running domino server for XPages development.

I'm using domcfg.nsf to redirect user logins to a $$LoginUserForm within the nsf.

I'm inputting directly 127.0.0.1 in the field 'Web Site/Virtual Server' of the 'Sign In' Form Mapping and also in the 'Web Site Document', field 'Host names or addresses mapped to this site'.

All is well - until I work on two separate databases at the same time.

What's the best practice here?

Manually updating the Internet Web Site Documents and the domcfg.nsf 'Sign In' Form Mapping? Some sort of trickery with my own DNS Server?

Looking forwards to any suggestions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add "fake" hostnames to your local hosts file and then use these hostnames on your local Domino server for the internet web site documents and domcfg.

Comment: On OS X you can edit `/private/etc/hosts`, on Windows `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`. Simply add a line with the IP address (127.0.0.1) and the hostname that you want to use. As a best practice I use the `.local` extension on those hostnames e.g. `domino.local`